# ES6: How to Import and Export modules and keep access from console

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, uikit, babeljs

Usually I can trigger UIkit functions from the console like:

```
UIkit.alert('.myalert').close();
```

I have this small example where I use UIkit and a dummy function. 
When compiling this i no longer have access over the console:

```
import UIkit from 'uikit';
import Icons from './uikit/uikit-icons';
UIkit.use(Icons);

import Myfunction from './myfunction';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    Myfunction('something');
})
```

I added this to export UIkit with no luck:

```
export default { UIkit };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `window.UIkit = UIkit` after `import`

Comment: This works, but is this approach a problem for memory management? Does this lead to two UIkits running in parallel?

Comment: No its the same instance, just that it is now a global variable accessible from the console

Comment: OK, thanks. I still don't understand why vanilla UIkit is accessible over console. They are just doing `export default UIkit` from `uikit.js`

Comment: Its not an issue with `UIkit`, but any module in general using the ES6 `import / export` syntax

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to be `export default UIkit;`
Because now you export an object with `UIkit` being it's key.
But you also need to import `UIkit` to `myfunction` as well.

Comment: I tried `export default UIkit` too, but there was no access from console possible.

Comment: Another approach is to create a file where you do `window.UIkit = UIkit`, and after that you have to `import './<filename>'` in your main file.

Comment: FWIW, this answer does not really address the problem. OP is using property value shorthand, a feature from ES6